# Limit of 1/x as x approaches infinity

Tags: limits, infinity

Why is $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{x}$ equal to $0$, when really the limit appears to be an infinitesimal quantity?

I am trying to understand why there is no distinction between 0 and an infinitesimal quantity in the context of limits.

Comment: If you leave it as an inifinitesimal you get non-standard analysis.

Comment: @Parcly: $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x} = 0$ holds true in nonstandard analysis too. (As it must, due to the transfer principle)

Comment: @amWhy: That alleged duplicate doesn't appear to address the OP's misconceptions at all.

Comment: I disagree, @Hurkyl

Comment: @amWhy The alleged duplicate *definitely* isn't a duplicate - that question is about using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ machinery, whereas this question is about infinitesimals (or their absence) in calculus; this question doesn't ask anything about using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ arguments, and the alleged duplicate (as well as its answers) doesn't ever mention infinitesimals.

Comment: To the OP: why did you get rid of the motivating sentence? It clarified the question a lot, in particular distinguishing it from a possible duplicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In standard real analysis/calculus, there are no infinitesimal quantities. Everything is formulated in terms of real numbers. What $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = c$ means is that for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $x_o\in \mathbb{R}$ such that whenever $x>x_0$, we have that $\vert f(x)-c\vert < \varepsilon$. In words, what this means is that if you pick and small number $\varepsilon$, you can find a number $x_0$ large enough such  that at any number past $x_0$, $f(x)$ will be no greater than a distance $\varepsilon$ away from $c$. For example, if $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ and $c=0$, this is the case. Given $\varepsilon > 0$, we can let $x_0 = 1/\varepsilon$; then if $x>x_0$, we have $\vert f(x)-0\vert = 1/x < \varepsilon$. So, $1/x$ really does approach $0$, in that it gets arbitrarily close to $0$.

Comment: Strictly speaking, there's no such thing as an infinitesimal quantity in any calculus, under the standard formulation. Even derivatives and integrals are defined in terms of limits, and their definitions never appeal to anything but ordinary real numbers.

Comment: Is there a reason why calculus was defined to only appeal to real numbers?

Comment: @Math12345 Because it's part of the study of the real numbers. The standard definition of limit is the one which is appropriate to the subject. We could introduce infinitesimals and redefine limits as you suggest, but then we'd be studying a different thing. This is true even if we [use infinitesimals to do calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_analysis): even here, the statement "$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}{1\over x}=0$" is true! The infinitesimals function as a tool for understanding the reals, and as an extension of them; they don't change the basic behavior.

Answer (score 5):

In the early days of calculus the idea of infinitesimals or "vanishingly small quantities" different from $0$ was used somewhat freely although those doing so knew that they had no rigorous justification for doing so.

At some point mathematicians such as Cauchy and Bolzano tried to treat the notion of limit with more rigor by taming the concept of "infinity" in their arguments.

But it was Weierstrass who finally put this into the form of a definition, the $\epsilon, \delta$ definition which we know today.

Thus mathematicians could speak plainly and say that

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}=0$$

rather than trying to explain what they meant by "the smallest possible number greater than $0$" or other circumlocutions.

In modern times others tried to logically incorporate a notion of "infinitesimals" into calculus in what is called "non-standard analysis."

Answer (score 3):

If the limit appears to be an infinitesimal quantity, then you probably have one of the common fundamental misconceptions about limits are doing.

In particular, you are failing to conceive of the *limit*, but are instead thinking of the behavior of the function *near* the limit.

Misconceptions about $\pm \infty$ often muddle the issue here. For comparison, note that  $\lim_{x \to 0} x$ is also *exactly* zero, not merely 'infinitesimal'. $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x}$ isn't fundamentally any different from $\lim_{x \to 0} x$, but sometimes the fact $\infty$ is involved sometimes gives people a mental block.

Comment: @Math12345: $x$ never becomes zero as $x \to 0$ either.

Comment: In the first case (using the limit of the function $f(x)$ as $x \to 0$) is not comparable to the second function to which you refer.  One is defined at $x = 0$, and the other isn't.

Answer (score 0):

The limit of an equation also affects the answer. An infinitesimal is a limit to 0, but since the lim symbol is already there, we can write it as 0.

Comment: Not the limit of an *equation* (something = 0), but the limit of a *function* or of an expression.