# Why doesn't calculus make a distinction between 0 and an infinitessimal quantity?

Tags: calculus, limits

Limits only rely on real numbers. Why?

Background: [Limit of 1/x as x approaches infinity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2270193/limit-of-1-x-as-x-approaches-infinity/2270211#2270211)

Comment: How would you define them otherwise?

Comment: You shouldn't have posted a second question undistinguishable from the first one, which has had many (good) answers.

Comment: Looking at your other questions/comments, I don't think anyone can satisfactorily answer until you explicitly define: limit, real number, infinitesimal. I suspect that last one will be tricky.

Comment: Ok, thanks all for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I look at it.

Calculus is the study of change (Well, basic Calculus as far as I know). The change between f(x)->0 or infinity and g(x)->0 or infinity strictly depends on how fast those two equation themselves are changing. As, f(x) can be 2x and g(x) can be e^x. They both approach infinity as x approach infinity, they both approach 0 as x approach 0, but one is clearly approaching infinity faster then the other.

The same reasoning can be applied if f(x)/g(x) - > 0 if f(x) = 1/x while g(x) = x^(googol). They both approach towards infinity and zero, but the speed at which they approach has yet been indeterminate.

Note: googol means really large number.

For reasoning with more mathematically rigor, look up Indeterminate form/L'Hôpital's rule.