# Choosing a number from infinite numbers

Tags: probability, infinity

Imagine infinite set of, let's say, natural numbers. I choose one of the infinite numbers randomly. Let's call that number *n*. If I choose another number too, can it be the same number (*n*), theoretically?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: What are your own thoughts on this?  Intuitive, it would seem yes, sure, why couldn't the second be the same as the first?  But since you posted this question, I assume you have some doubts or concerns?  What are those? Can you please express those in your post?

Comment: What do you mean by "randomly"? Do you mean that any number has the same probability of being selected?

Comment: How do choose your number? You need a probability distribution, and note that as probability distributions are countably additive, if you make one on a countable set (such as the natural numbers) not all elements can have the same probability.

Comment: @G.Chiusole Yeah, any number has the same probability of being selected.

Comment: As Henrik points out, such a probability measure does not exist

Comment: @Bram28 Well, you have a very good point there. I have no idea. Infinity is itself is like a paradox, it's not yet fully known.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, there is no way that each natural can have the same probability. See [this answer to "Can you pick a random natural number?...](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/997213/26369), for instance.

However, we can still pick a number randomly with *un*equal probabilities. For instance, suppose I choose a number by flipping a coin, and the number is the number of heads before the first tail. (If you want to include a case of flipping heads forever, let's say that also counts as the number $0$.)

I just got the following sequences of flips: $HHT,T,HT,T$. Which means that the number $0$ was randomly selected twice.

Answer (score 0):

I'd loved to put this in a comment, but I can't because I am new here.

I just wanted to say that since you picked that particular number the first time, it has a non-zero probability of being picked. Thus it definitely can be picked again.

Comment: Possible does not necessarily mean "non-zero probability". See [Zero probability and impossibility](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/41107/26369).

Comment: Oh I see, you are right. That was a bad choice of words from me. I should have said that "it is pickable" instead of "has a non-zero probability of being picked". However I could even argue that the limit of $k/x$ for k > 0 and x tending to infinity it's not exactly 0, but a bit more than that.

Comment: "It is pickable" would be fine. For your other comment, even in nonstandard analysis where there are a variety of infinities and infinitesimals, we would still say the limit is exactly $0$.

Comment: But take for example 1/x, the function never "touches" the horizontal axis. For any value of x arbitrarily large there always will be an e : 0 < e < 1/x

Comment: By reading this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2270193/limit-of-1-x-as-x-approaches-infinity#:~:text=In%20standard%20real%20analysis%2Fcalculus,)%E2%88%92c%7C%3C%CE%B5.&text=So%2C%201%2Fx%20really%20does,gets%20arbitrarily%20close%20to%200.
I've understood that yes, we say that the limit is 0, but when we say so we actually mean that it is arbitrarily close to zero. So I may conclude that in a certain way we are both right.